# Show data more than 2 dimension in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am currently using the GA4 reporting function.
However, I notice it is only possible to have a 2 dimensional reporting, is it possible to have add a 3rd or 4th layer of dimension to the data itself?

[Reporting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MII1q.png)

[Explore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHytw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can combine many dimensions and metrics in the Explorer view like so:

[image]

GA4 is cheap. The data you see in Reporting is not real. It's just snapshots of aggregates. Google introduced new "feature" of limiting data retention to 2 month by default and 14 months optionally for free accounts (48 months for paid).

Reporting will show graphs for more than that, but these graphs are not based on raw data. They're based on snapshots. That's why you won't be able to meaningfully drill into them or use additional dimensions freely as you used to in UA.

Moreover, they do that aggregate data snapshoting in an odd way. It doesn't coinside with similar Explorer reports or raw data. For now, it's the best practice to not use Reports. Either use Explorer or extract the data and use something else.

Comment: Hi there, please compare to the two image on reporting and explore mode, it doesn't have the data we needed.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work with custom dimension which is quite odd to me

Comment: I am not able to see any data in explore. Its odd.

Comment: Well, you're likely misusing the Explorer. Or you don't have the data. Check your data retention settings. Try exporting it to BQ for free and see if it's there.

Comment: The data retention setting is current 2 months. I can see in the report but not in the explorer view which is odd.

Comment: On data retention i can only see two option: 
Event data retention

Reset user data on new activity : Check or unchecked.

Comment: That data retention at two months means GA throws away all your raw data after it becomes two months old. Explorer only uses real data, so it's a subject to the data retention rules. Reports don't use the raw data, being just snapshots of data. But exactly due to them not being generated based on raw data, there's VERY little you can do to them. In short: GA4 is much less useful than UA used to be.

Comment: I still don't understand why the data is showing on the report side but not the explorer view. Its quite weird.

Comment: because it's not data that's showing on reports. It's almost screenshots of data. Screenshots take a lot less space for google to store, so it can do it for years. unlike the original data.

Comment: So how can I make the data show up in the explorer view?

Comment: change your retention from 2 months to 14. And wait till you collect enough data since GA4 deleted all your data that was older than 2 months since you didn't configure the data retention right away.

Comment: The data itself was already less than 2 months old. I don't understand why it wasn't sending the dat